# Different directory structures when unzipping the same file in Ubuntu vs. Windows

Tags: python, zip

I am trying to extract the contents of a zip file, which can be viewed here:

https://www.geoboundaries.org/data/geoBoundaries-2_0_0/NGA/ADM1/geoBoundaries-2_0_0-NGA-ADM1-all.zip

On Ubuntu 18.04.04, with the 'extract' option from the right click menu, I get a folder structure from that zip file that includes all sorts of empty folders and directories, as well as a different parent.  If I unzip the same file using 7Zip (on a windows or the same linux box), I get the expected result of 6 files.

So - what's the difference here?

(Note I already have a solution - shutil archive works - just trying to understand the different behaviors).

This is the code (python) currently being used to build the zips in question:

```
def zipdir(dirPath=None, zipFilePath=None, includeDirInZip=False, citeUsePath=False):
  if not zipFilePath:
    zipFilePath = dirPath + ".zip"
  if not os.path.isdir(dirPath):
    raise OSError("dirPath argument must point to a directory. "
            "'%s' does not." % dirPath)
  parentDir, dirToZip = os.path.split(dirPath)

  def trimPath(path):
    archivePath = path.replace(parentDir, "", 1)
    if parentDir:
      archivePath = archivePath.replace(os.path.sep, "", 1)
    if not includeDirInZip:
      archivePath = archivePath.replace(dirToZip + os.path.sep, "", 1)
    return os.path.normcase(archivePath)

  outFile = zipfile.ZipFile(zipFilePath, "w",compression=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
  for (archiveDirPath, dirNames, fileNames) in os.walk(dirPath):
    for fileName in fileNames:
      if(not fileName == zipFilePath.split("/")[-1]):
        filePath = os.path.join(archiveDirPath, fileName)
        outFile.write(filePath, trimPath(filePath))

  outFile.write(citeUsePath, os.path.basename(citeUsePath))
  outFile.close()
```

Comment: What `extract` facility did you use?  This would be something launched through an IDE you haven't specified: so far as I know, Ubuntu is only a Linux distro, and does not have a built-in `extract`.  You've done a good job of narrowing the problem to this facility.

Comment: If the build script is truly needed for this question, please reduce it to minimal code: remove the error-checking, and hard-code a local file name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The zip file `geoBoundaries-2_0_0-NGA-ADM1-all.zip` is non-standard.

On Linux, `unzip` thinks that there are 5 files with no path components

```
$ unzip -l geoBoundaries-2_0_0-NGA-ADM1-all.zip
Archive:  geoBoundaries-2_0_0-NGA-ADM1-all.zip
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
   374953  2020-01-15 21:04   geoBoundaries-2_0_0-NGA-ADM1-shp.zip
  1512980  2020-01-15 21:04   geoBoundaries-2_0_0-NGA-ADM1.geojson
      804  2020-01-15 21:04   geoBoundaries-2_0_0-NGA-ADM1-metaData.json
      750  2020-01-15 21:04   geoBoundaries-2_0_0-NGA-ADM1-metaData.txt
     4656  2020-01-15 21:04   CITATION-AND-USE-geoBoundaries-2_0_0.txt
---------                     -------
  1894143                     5 files
```

If I then try to extract the contents I get a lot of warnings.

```
$ unzip  geoBoundaries-2_0_0-NGA-ADM1-all.zip
Archive:  geoBoundaries-2_0_0-NGA-ADM1-all.zip
geoBoundaries-2_0_0-NGA-ADM1-shp.zip:  mismatching "local" filename (release/geoBoundaries-2_0_0/NGA/ADM1/geoBoundaries-2_0_0-NGA-ADM1-shp.zip),
         continuing with "central" filename version
  inflating: geoBoundaries-2_0_0-NGA-ADM1-shp.zip
geoBoundaries-2_0_0-NGA-ADM1.geojson:  mismatching "local" filename (release/geoBoundaries-2_0_0/NGA/ADM1/geoBoundaries-2_0_0-NGA-ADM1.geojson),
         continuing with "central" filename version
  inflating: geoBoundaries-2_0_0-NGA-ADM1.geojson
geoBoundaries-2_0_0-NGA-ADM1-metaData.json:  mismatching "local" filename (release/geoBoundaries-2_0_0/NGA/ADM1/geoBoundaries-2_0_0-NGA-ADM1-metaData.json),
         continuing with "central" filename version
  inflating: geoBoundaries-2_0_0-NGA-ADM1-metaData.json
geoBoundaries-2_0_0-NGA-ADM1-metaData.txt:  mismatching "local" filename (release/geoBoundaries-2_0_0/NGA/ADM1/geoBoundaries-2_0_0-NGA-ADM1-metaData.txt),
         continuing with "central" filename version
  inflating: geoBoundaries-2_0_0-NGA-ADM1-metaData.txt
CITATION-AND-USE-geoBoundaries-2_0_0.txt:  mismatching "local" filename (tmp/CITATION-AND-USE-geoBoundaries-2_0_0.txt),
         continuing with "central" filename version
  inflating: CITATION-AND-USE-geoBoundaries-2_0_0.txt
```

**Analysis**

The details for each entry in a zip file, including the filename, are stored twice. Once in a `local-header`, directly before the compressed data and again in a `central-header` at the end of the file. So for every file stored in a zip file there will be a `local-header` / `central-header` pair of fields. The data in these pairs of fields should be (mostly) identical.

In this instance they are not.

For example, consider the `central-header` entry for `geoBoundaries-2_0_0-NGA-ADM1-shp.zip`. The matching `local-header` has `release/geoBoundaries-2_0_0/NGA/ADM1/geoBoundaries-2_0_0-NGA-ADM1-shp.zip`.

The same is true for all the entries in this zip file.

Given that this is a non-standard/invalid zip file, the behaviour when unzipping will be down to whether the unzipping utility uses the data in the `central-header` entry to determine the filenames or if it uses the equivalent data in the `local-header`.

Looks like Ubuntu is using the `local-header` fields while 7zip uses the `central-header` fields.

For reference the spec for zip files is [APPNOTE.TXT](https://pkware.cachefly.net/webdocs/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT)

Comment: Is there anything in the specs on how this should be handled? Fail if both names differ? Prefer central one over local one? Another way?

Comment: It really depends on the use case.  If you want an application that strictly conforms to the spec, it should fail if the `local-header` doesn't match the `central-header`. The standard desktop/commanline applications will give preference to the `central-header` and emit a warning as in this use case.